# How to unscale Neural Network Predictions

Tags: r, dataframe, neural-network, scale

I scaled my data and ran the neuralnet model on a training set, results came out good so I tried it on new data.  But my output is still scaled-down, can I unscale it? I used my whole database (totalann_dbase_z) to train, and the prediction set is whole new dataframe with the same variables (week12_dbase), but does not contain any target variable data yet, as the games have yet to be played.

```
week12_train <- totalann_dbase_z[1:162, ] 
week12_test <- week12_dbase_z[1:14, ] 
week12_model <- neuralnet(ï..Total.Pts ~ ., data = week12_train)  
week12_model_results <- compute(week12_model, week12_test[1:31]) 
print(week12_model_results$net.result)

[,1] 
1  -0.3159784 
2   0.9800863 
3  -0.5324439 
4   0.9407832 
5  -0.5324439 
6   0.8970504 
7  -0.5290323 
8  -0.5324439 
9  -0.5324439 
10 -0.5324439 
11 -0.5324439 
12 -0.5324438 
13  0.9800683 
14  0.9800864
```

Any concise way to just unscale that vector/column?  Create a function maybe?  Or is there an unscale() command already?  I tried unscale() for fun, but got errors that it never heard of it.

Comment: What you are showing is not valid R code. If you used the `scale` function, note that the original mean and standard deviation have been preserved as attributes. Multiplying by the standard deviation and adding the mean will unscale the predictions.

Comment: I'm new to R, so by not "valid" what do you mean?  I'm assuming "not valid" would mean I get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the unscaling method you used, the first thing that you have to do is preserving the scaling factors that you have previously used to scale your data. If I am not mistaken, those come from all columns in your training data. The standard properties of scaling factors are the mean and standard deviation of each column. The `scale()` function will automatically scale a numeric matrix or data frame by its column. It keeps the mean and standard deviation of each column as the scaling factors in its attributes. An example of a scaling procedure on a two-columns data frame is as follows.

```
data.1 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(10), c2 = rnorm(10, 5, 2))
```

The data are

```
(data.1)

##            c1           c2
## 1   0.3772471 -0.009461602
## 2   0.4699993  6.437574717
## 3   0.7436121  2.491381059
## 4  -0.6511270  5.087134339
## 5  -1.0583016  6.618780052
## 6   1.4937440  6.102453550
## 7   0.3884317  4.856061369
## 8   0.4208206  5.548549865
## 9  -2.2471531  5.277538678
## 10 -0.2600908  7.497727819
```

The scaled version is

```
data.1.scaled <- scale(data.1)
(data.1.scaled)
##               c1          c2
##  [1,]  0.3860826 -2.26312966
##  [2,]  0.4735246  0.65482868
##  [3,]  0.7314726 -1.13123675
##  [4,] -0.5834152  0.04361314
##  [5,] -0.9672784  0.73684305
##  [6,]  1.4386581  0.50315129
##  [7,]  0.3966269 -0.06097155
##  [8,]  0.4271614  0.25245193
##  [9,] -2.0880661  0.12979102
## [10,] -0.2147666  1.13465886
## attr(,"scaled:center")
##          c1          c2 
## -0.03228177  4.99077398 
## attr(,"scaled:scale")
##       c1       c2 
## 1.060729 2.209434
```

The attribute `scaled:center` is the mean of each column and `scaled:scale` is the standard deviation. We can utilize these attributes as scaling factors on other data.

```
data.2 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(5, 5, 2), c2 = rnorm(5, 10,3))
```

The second data:

```
(data.2)
##         c1       c2
## 1 3.383793 9.790161
## 2 4.942863 8.953490
## 3 6.142607 9.301666
## 4 9.194484 8.823053
## 5 5.442842 7.044456
```

The scaled data.2 using data.1 scaling factors:

```
data.2.scaled <- scale(data.2, center = attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:center'), scale = attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:scale'))
```

The scaled version of data.2:

```
(data.2.scaled)
##            c1       c2
## [1,] 3.220498 2.172225
## [2,] 4.690309 1.793544
## [3,] 5.821365 1.951129
## [4,] 8.698517 1.734507
## [5,] 5.161664 0.929506
## attr(,"scaled:center")
##          c1          c2 
## -0.03228177  4.99077398 
## attr(,"scaled:scale")
##       c1       c2 
## 1.060729 2.209434
```

Note that the attributes is presented in a vectored variable having the same length as the data columns. It can also be used to unscale the scaled data. We can employ `apply()` and `t()` functions to perform the procedure.

To data.1:

```
data.1.unscaled <- t(apply(data.1.scaled, 1, function(input) {
  (input * attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:scale')) +
    attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:center')
}))
```

To data.2:

```
data.2.unscaled <- t(apply(data.2.scaled, 1, function(input) {
  (input * attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:scale')) +
    attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:center')
}))
```

Now let us check the unscaled data with the original data, they must be identical.

```
cbind(data.1, data.1.unscaled)
##            c1           c2         c1           c2
## 1   0.3772471 -0.009461602  0.3772471 -0.009461602
## 2   0.4699993  6.437574717  0.4699993  6.437574717
## 3   0.7436121  2.491381059  0.7436121  2.491381059
## 4  -0.6511270  5.087134339 -0.6511270  5.087134339
## 5  -1.0583016  6.618780052 -1.0583016  6.618780052
## 6   1.4937440  6.102453550  1.4937440  6.102453550
## 7   0.3884317  4.856061369  0.3884317  4.856061369
## 8   0.4208206  5.548549865  0.4208206  5.548549865
## 9  -2.2471531  5.277538678 -2.2471531  5.277538678
## 10 -0.2600908  7.497727819 -0.2600908  7.497727819


cbind(data.2, data.2.unscaled)
##         c1       c2       c1       c2
## 1 3.383793 9.790161 3.383793 9.790161
## 2 4.942863 8.953490 4.942863 8.953490
## 3 6.142607 9.301666 6.142607 9.301666
## 4 9.194484 8.823053 9.194484 8.823053
## 5 5.442842 7.044456 5.442842 7.044456
```

If you have a scaled values (I sampled from column #2 of both data frame) and want to unscaled it using a certain scaling factor (say column 2 also),

```
set.seed(1)
one.column.scaled <- data.frame(x = sample(c(data.1.scaled[,2], data.2.scaled[,2]), 5))
(one.column.scaled)
##             x
## 1  0.12979102
## 2  0.04361314
## 3 -0.06097155
## 4 -2.26312966
## 5  0.65482868
```

then you can perform the unscaling procedure without calling `apply()` and `t()` functions.

```
one.column.unscaled <- (one.column.scaled * attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:scale')[2]) + 
  attr(data.1.scaled, 'scaled:center')[2]

(one.column.unscaled)
##              x
## 1  5.277538678
## 2  5.087134339
## 3  4.856061369
## 4 -0.009461602
## 5  6.437574717
```